# Criando um dataframe tendo como base outros dois dataframes usando dplyr no R

Tags: r, dplyr

Esses são os meus dataframes:

```
df<-    as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(200),, 25))
colnames(df)<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
        "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
        "U","V","X","Z","W")


df.new<-as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(200),,20))
colnames(df.new)<-c("A.B","A.B.new",
            "A.C","A.C.new",
            "A.F","A.F.new",
                "B.C","B.C.new",
                    "C.D","C.D.new",
                    "F.G","F.G.new",
                "H.I","H.I.new",
                    "H.K","H.K.new",
                    "L.M","L.M.new",
            "N.Q","N.Q.new")
df.new<-df.new[-c(9:10),]


finaldf<-cbind(df,df.new)
colnames(finaldf)<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
        "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
        "U","V","X","Z","W","A.B","A.B.new",
            "A.C","A.C.new",
            "A.F","A.F.new",
                "B.C","B.C.new",
                    "C.D","C.D.new",
                    "F.G","F.G.new",
                "H.I","H.I.new",
                    "H.K","H.K.new",
                    "L.M","L.M.new",
            "N.Q","N.Q.new")
```

Eu gostaria de fazer com que o dataframe `finaldf` ordenasse as colunas assim:

```
colnames(finaldf)<-c("A","A.B","A.B.new",
            "A","A.C","A.C.new",
            "A","A.F","A.F.new",
            "B","B.C","B.C.new",
            "C","C.D","C.D.new",
            "F","F.G","F.G.new",
            "H","H.I","H.I.new",
            "H","H.K","H.K.new",
            "L","L.M","L.M.new",
            "N","N.Q","N.Q.new")
```

Como meu dataframe original é muito maior, devo precisar de um codigo mais robusto, que foge a minha capacidade tendo em vista q sou nova no R.

Repare que a ideia é simplesmente pega colunas do dataframe df e jogar no dataframe df.new. Mas essas colunas devem se encaixar na ordem estabelecida pelo dataframe df.new.

E gostaria de fazer isso usando o dplyr package. É possivel?

**Editado:**

Bom, o meu codigo original vem com os nomes das açoões da bovespa:

```
nms.new<-c("ABEV3.BBAS3", "ABEV3.BBAS3.new", "ABEV3.BRAP4", "ABEV3.BRAP4.new", 
"ABEV3.BRKM5", "ABEV3.BRKM5.new", "ABEV3.CSAN3", "ABEV3.CSAN3.new", 
"ABEV3.CSNA3", "ABEV3.CSNA3.new", "ABEV3.CYRE3", "ABEV3.CYRE3.new", 
"ABEV3.DTEX3", "ABEV3.DTEX3.new", "ABEV3.ELPL4", "ABEV3.ELPL4.new", 
"ABEV3.EVEN3", "ABEV3.EVEN3.new", "ABEV3.FIBR3", "ABEV3.FIBR3.new", 
"ABEV3.GGBR4", "ABEV3.GGBR4.new", "ABEV3.GOAU4", "ABEV3.GOAU4.new", 
"ABEV3.HYPE3", "ABEV3.HYPE3.new", "ABEV3.JBSS3", "ABEV3.JBSS3.new","SANB11.BBAS3","SANB11.BBAS3.new")
```

Eu precisaria separar o que vem antes e depois do ponto e não de 1 em 1. As vezes vem 5 letras antes do ponto, outras vezes vem 6 letras.

Comment: A coluna `A` aparece 3 vezes, é assim mesmo? Repetida antes de cada `A.C` e `A.F`? E o mesmo para `B`, `C`, etc?

Comment: Exato @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui vai.
O truque é agrupar pelos primeiros caracteres de `names(finaldf)` e depois processar a lista de grupos.

Primeiro escolhemos os `names` que interessam.

```
nms <- names(finaldf)
nms <- nms[sapply(nms, nchar) > 1]
```

Agora agrupam-se pelos 3 primeiros caracteres.

```
sp <- split(nms, substr(nms, 1, 3))
nms <- lapply(sp, function(s) c(substr(s[1], 1, 1), s))
nms <- unlist(nms)
result <- finaldf[nms]
```

O resultado `result` tem as dimensões da pergunta.

```
dim(result)
#[1]  8 30
```

Mas cuidado, como não pode haver nomes repetidos, haverá `A`, `A.1` e `A.2`. E a mesma coisa para quaisquer outros onde haja repetições, por exemplo `H.I` e `H.K`.

```
names(result)
# [1] "A"       "A.B"     "A.B.new" "A.1"     "A.C"     "A.C.new"
# [7] "A.2"     "A.F"     "A.F.new" "B"       "B.C"     "B.C.new"
#[13] "C"       "C.D"     "C.D.new" "F"       "F.G"     "F.G.new"
#[19] "H"       "H.I"     "H.I.new" "H.1"     "H.K"     "H.K.new"
#[25] "L"       "L.M"     "L.M.new" "N"       "N.Q"     "N.Q.new"
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pelo esforço  @Rui Narradas! Funciona Perfeitamente! como mencionei meu dataframe original tem mais de 200 colunas. Alem disso eu devo agrupar pelos 5 primeiros caracteres. Como eu modificaria sua resposta? `sp <- split(nms, substr(nms, 1, 5))
nms <- lapply(sp, function(s) c(substr(s[1], 1, 1), s))
nms <- unlist(nms)
result <- finaldf[nms]` Mas obtenho a seguinte mensagem: `Error in `[.data.frame`(finaldf.1, nms.new) : undefined columns selected`

Comment: @Laura Pode dar um exemplo dos nomes com os 5 primeiros caracteres? De preferência editando a pergunta, por favor.

Comment: editei la. É sobre aqueles nomes que eu devo trabalhar, do meu dataframe original. Agora a regra muda, quando eu separo eu devo separar antes e depois do ponto. Pq se vc for reparar tem nomes que tem 5 letras  antes do ponto e nomes com 6 letras antes do ponto. Para obter o `sp`eu fiz assim: `split(nms.new, gsub("\\.new$", "", nms.new))`. Depois para obter o nms entra a questão de antes do ponto ter 5 letras ou 6 letras. Isso prejudica o restante do codigo.